# Is this a good security/validation method to use in WCF services?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, hash, cryptography

I am creating a host/client style that uses WCF and its wsHttpBinding to communicate clients to a server running the host and I wanted to provide some sort of security or validation so I have this and I was wondering how good or secure it is.

Every method in the service library has a USERNAME and PASSWORD variable which have to both be populated with a value that gets hashed by the client using the SHA512 hash algorithm. So the username, password and any other parameters for the method are sent along to the server which will check the hashed username and password against a database of hashed usernames and passwords to see if a match is found. If it does match then it returns the data that the client requested but if it does not match then it returns an error or message and doesn't send back the data. A code snipped of a method with this 'security' is below:

```
// The USERNAME and PASSWORD parameter values have been hashed by the client before
[OperationContract]
string SayHello(string USERNAME, string PASSWORD, string name)

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

public string SayHello(string USERNAME, string PASSWORD, string name)
{
    if (USERNAME == "username" & PASSWORD == "password")
    { return string.Format("Hello, {0}!", name); }
    else { return "Invalid credentials, method aborted"; }
}
```

Is this a good security method for validating 'calls'? It is more on the side of checking that they have an account as opposed to being secure but I think it may be quite secure. What do you think, how secure or good is it but more importantly, how could it be broken by hackers or other methods?

Answer (score 1):

This article should help you: [How to: Authenticate with a User Name and Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
WSHttpBinding userNameBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
userNameBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
userNameBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), userNameBinding, "");
...

string username;
string password;

// Instantiate the proxy
Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();

// Prompt the user for username & password
GetPassword(out username, out password);

// Set the user’s credentials on the proxy
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

// Treat the test certificate as trusted
proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = 
    System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
// Call the service operation using the proxy
```